# Flashbuilder: ActionScript only Project, compiler metadata

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

If one creates an ActionScript only project in Flash builder, one can set things like stage size and framerate as metadata like this

```
[SWF(width='400', height='300', backgroundColor='#ffffff', frameRate='30')]
```

as described here: http://www.adrianparr.com/?p=36

I wanted to ask what other settings i can set using such metadata? is there somewhere a complete list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Adobe's documentation:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf680e1-7ffe.html